# How to decode video data from specific position in byte?

Tags: ffmpeg

I can initialize the decoder and decode video file from start of the file. But now what I have is the byte position of the file. And I want to decode from that position. How can I seek to the specific position.
I tried the method

```
av_seek_frame(AVFormatContext, stream_index, timestamp, AVSEEK_FLAG_BYTE);
```

and use the method

```
av_read_frame()
```

But it can not seek to the right position. I get the same frame when I change 'timestamp'.  Can anyone help me to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

When you apply a seek with `AVSEEK_FLAG_BYTE` flag, it does not mean that the next frame to read exactly at this point. In any case, ffmpeg searches for the next correct frame.

Comment: when I used the AV_SEEK_FLAG_BYTE, it always seek the same frame even when I changed the 'timestamp'. And the frame I seek is also not the keyframe. So how can I can seek the byte position to find the next key frame of the posision?

Comment: @JornStrong Perform seek to the target position, then read frames until you find a key frame (in the target stream)

Comment: what I did is just seeking to the specifid byte position, then use the fuction av_read_frame. But it always return the same frame.And the frame number sames like 12.

Comment: I have aready test my program and it passed. haha , thank you